# How to handle event when clicking outside of component?

Tags: reactjs

I reactjs I have a component and it has this code to detect whether there is a click outside the component:

```
export class Cart extends React.Component {
handleClick(e) {
            if (!ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).contains(e.target)) {
                console.log('testing=e.target', e.target)
            }
}

componentWillMount() {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
}

render()
{
   return (<div>hello</div>)
}}
```

However I am getting an error in the findDOMNode statement:

```
Uncaught Error: Element appears to be neither ReactComponent nor DOMNode
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add id property to the div component, and then refactor the code as follows:

```
export class Cart extends React.Component {
  handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.id === 'div') {
      console.log('inside')
    } else {
      console.log('outside!')
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <div id="div">
        hello
      </div>)
  }
}
```